# Angular ERROR: PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string

Tags: css, angular, build, postcss

Trying to build an Angular project and I'm getting the errors below. This project built fine last week. I made some changes to other projects that use the Dlls from this project, but no changes to this project. I already spent a lot of time troubleshooting it with no luck and appreciate any help.

> ERROR: PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string
> An unhandled exception occurred: PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had similar problem. I was trying to build an angular library and the message below appeared:

```
Building Angular Package

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building entry point 'library-name'
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
ERROR: PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string
An unhandled exception occurred: PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string
See "/tmp/ng-itlEgm/angular-errors.log" for further details.
[12:03:38] 'compile' errored after 17 s
[12:03:38] Error: Command `ng build library-name --prod` exited with code 127
    at ChildProcess.handleSubShellExit (/node_modules/gulp-run/command.js:166:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:505:15)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
[12:03:38] 'build' errored after 17 s
```

I was using `gulp-run` to execute the command `ng build library-name --prod`. But, executing the command `ng build library-name --prod` directly on the terminal, the log error was smaller, but similar too.

The problem was in one component. The component had one styleURL (Angular component decorator), like this:

`...component.css`

but, the library uses `scss`. So, I changed the path to:

`...component.scss`

and I executed the command 'ng build library-name --prod'. So, the error didn't appear again.

I was using NVM v0.35.2 (allow to have more than one NodeJS version installed in my machine); NodeJS v12.18.2; Ubuntu x64 18.0.4 LTS and Angular CLI 9.1.9.

Answer (score 109):

This can sometimes happen if `node-sass` was compiled for a different version of Node.js than you're currently running (ie if you've recently changed your Node.js version). You can fix that with:

```sh
npm rebuild node-sass
```

Comment: Did not work at first, had to run `npm install` after running `npm rebuild node-sass` before it worked for me

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me in a Vue 2.x project that started throwing this error

Comment: After use this command: npm i node-sass -D 

It works for me as charm

Comment: I uninstalled node-sass and didn't realize it was a dependency on packagr for Angular project (old style of build - upgrading...but need old for testing)

Comment: Thanks Google!!

Comment: This also solved my problem!

Comment: This did not help for. I followed the answer by @noreply which worked for me. I am running vuejs instead of angular.

Comment: Depends on whether you use node-sass or dart-sass

Answer (score 73):

if you are using webpack, and trying to use `sass-loader`, also add `sass`

Comment: Odd I needed to add sass after adding sass-loader (using yarn and Vue 2.x), but that fixed it for me.

Comment: Sometimes I think what if there were no developer community. How could we poor devs would know that we have to manually add sass too :'D

Comment: The actual command I had to use was:
`npm install sass-loader sass webpack --save-dev`  
Taken from [https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/)

Answer (score 21):

I had this same issue when attempting to test an Angular library, and the issue was I had ``` [``] ``` instead of `[]` in the `styles` property of my component metadata.

Wrong

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-input',
template: `
  <input
  ... />
  `,
styles: [``],
```

Right

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-input',
template: `
  <input
  ... />
  `,
styles: [],
```

Comment: I had the same problem as a I upgraded from Angular 12.0.x to 12.4.x. The solution was to remove the `styles: [``]`

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same situation now and the command that helped me is -

```
npm i node-sass -D
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the node version, see if the version of node changes cause this problem. I use node version 16.14.2 which occured this error, after switch to 12.16.1 it works well. Just check your node-sass and node version will find a way out.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to change in version of node. I had same issue with a NUXT app. What I did was

1. using yarn, in the root directory of your project, run  `yarn`. But if you're using npm run `npm install`
2. start your project again.