# Vue2 - Error: PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, sass-loader

i have this problem when trying to compile a Vue2 project

```
Syntax Error: Error: PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string
 @ ./src/assets/sass/main.scss 4:14-233 14:3-18:5 15:22-241
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.202:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

I have tried to rebuild the sass-loader with no success.

My node version is v16.6.1
My NPM version is 7.21.0

Webpack is 5.1.2 and the sass-loader version is 10.2.0

This is a VUE2 project and all started when i started a new Vue3 project and i had to upgrade the vue/cli but i cannot understand how to go back locally (if this is the problem)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try it

```
npm install node-sass
or 
npm rebuild node-sass
```

I got answer for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66100070/8627079)

Comment: That helped for me but I had to follow the link where you got the answer from. I am running vuejs with webpack.

Comment: @DirkSchumacher It's great.

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: didn't work for me, but ```npm install sass``` worked

Answer (score 18):

Solved by first uninstalling `node-sass`:

`yarn remove node-sass`

And then installing `sass` instead:

`yarn add -D sass`

Comment: adding sass worked for me. using nuxtjs to use scss lang in style

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the same error and after downgrading the node version it was fixed.

Answer (score 5):

I resolved this issue by downgrading my version of "node-sass" to "^4.14.1":

```
npm install node-sass@4.14.1
```

Answer (score 1):

solved by switching to node v15.14.0

Answer (score 1):

This error, `Error: PostCSS received undefined instead of CSS string` is being thrown by `sass-loader`.

One solution would be to reinstall `sass-loader`. By using the following steps, the *sass compile error* should be fixed.

#### Steps for npm & yarn

**! Note**: If you have `node-sass` installed, you will need to *reinstall* it as well, by using the following commands:

```
# npm
npm uninstall sass-loader node-sass
npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev

# yarn
yarn remove sass-loader node-sass
yarn add sass-loader node-sass --dev
```

To *reinstall* `sass-loader` run these commands:

```
# npm
npm uninstall sass-loader
npm install sass-loader --save-dev

# yarn
yarn remove sass-loader
yarn add sass-loader --dev
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Hey, I was following a tutorial about VueJS, and I had the same error, tried to rebuild node-sass it didn't work.

Then I saw that the lang used in the style balise was SCSS (in the App.vue) , I changed it to CSS and it worked. :)

Comment: Imho, this is not a solution if the features of SCSS are used. It has it's own syntax and css is fully compatible but not vice versa if I am informed correctly. Check here: https://sass-lang.com/